# Web font (using @font-face) visible in web page but not visible on user's system controls

Tags: ios, css, fonts

I am building a web site in Myanmar Burmese language and I am so far successful in showing the Burmese font by using CSS like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Zawgyi-One;
  src: url('../../fonts/zawgyi.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../../fonts/zawgyi.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../../fonts/zawgyi.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../../fonts/zawgyi.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../../fonts/zawgyi.svg#Zawgyi-One') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

body {
  font-family: Zawgyi-one !important;
}
```

and it is working fine as long as the text is displayed in the browser.

However, when I open the website in iPhone, and click on one of the dropdown menus, the iOS system drop down shows up and shows gibberish instead of proper characters like so:

[image]

I suspect that happens because the iOS system dropdown is a operating system component and since the font is only installed in the web browser context, the system dropdown cannot render the font. Please correct me if I am wrong.

**Question:**

How do I show Burmese font correctly in iOS dropdowns?

a) without asking the user to download the Burmese font to his or her system?

b) can we even do that without the user installing the font in his or her system?

c) is there a way to automatically install the font to the user's system (I don't think its possible but please correct me if I am wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is because your font is accessible from the web page only and not available for the system. But you cannot directly install a font to the device. But it can be done using [configuration profiles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef.pdf) and I think [this is a good example how you want it to work](http://www.typography.com/faq/question.php?faqID=156). you can ask the user to download and install the font

[Here](http://nshipster.com/configuration-profiles/) is a bit more readable info about configuration profiles

Comment: Thanks @Antenehs - seems like configuration profiles are the only option ;-(

Answer (score 0):

You can simply expose the font in your Info.plist file. You need to add the `Fonts provided by application` key, so it looks like this:

[image]

The source looks like this:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>MyGreatFont.ttf</string>
</array>
```

That's all you need to do. iOS will automatically analyze your provided fonts and pick one that provides the characters that need to be displayed.